# Are there complete formal systems?

Tags: incompleteness

I am relatively new to logic, so forgive my ignorance. My question is: Are there any formal systems that are deemed complete? If so, how did we prove they were complete and which are they?

Comment: "Complete" in what sense?  There are certainly first-order theories which are complete (_e.g._ the theory of dense linear orders without endpoints), but these are not capable of encoding "mathematics" wide and large.

Answer (score 1):

Inconsistent theories are trivially complete, so I'm going to assume that you're looking for systems that are both consistent and complete.

One such system is [Presburger Arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presburger_arithmetic) (PreA), which resembles the usual Peano Arithmetic, but has no multiplication.

A common technique for showing completeness is **quantifier elimination**:
a theory admits quantifier elimination if every quantified formula corresponds to a logically equivalent quantifier-free formula.

Strictly speaking, PreA does not admit quantifier elimination, but a finite extension does: the resulting procedure is [Cooper's algorithm](http://www.cs.wm.edu/~idillig/cs780-02/Cooper.pdf).

Quantifier elimination, by itself, does not mean that your theory is complete: you also need to show that all quantifier-free statements are either provable or refutable. In the case of PreA and its extension, this follows by a simple structural induction.